# Regex for finding value inside parenthesis

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a line of code:

```
<link href="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Styles/CAR.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I just want to extract `~/Styles/CAR.css` from it.
Kindly let me know Regex for this.
link href tag may contain other syntax as well to refer css.
For Ex, `<link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Styles/CAR.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: I have a line of code:
<link href="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Styles/CAR.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
I just want to extract "~/Styles/CAR.css" from it.
Kindly let me know Regex for this.
link href tag may contain other syntax as well to refer css.
For Ex, <link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Styles/CAR.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: I was under the impression that bad things happen when you try to parse html with regex... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/24908  =)

Comment: `Page.ResolveClientUrl` and `Url.Content` don't necessarily result in the same output, so how would this be reliable? Why don't you parse the generated HTML instead of server-side code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides that you [should'nt parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), I'd go for

```
\(\"(.+)\"\)
```

as your regex. Simply extract anything between `("` and `")`.

For example:

```
string strRegex = @"\(\""(.+)\""\)";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"<link href=""<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl(""~/Styles/CAR.css"") %>"" rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" />";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```

(example code taken from http://regexhero.net/tester/)

If there will be only one occurence of `<link href=""<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl(""~/Styles/CAR.css"") %>"" rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" />` or you want to get only the first occurence, then you can get rid of the for-loop and use:

```
string strRegex = @"\(\""(.+)\""\)";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"<link href=""<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl(""~/Styles/CAR.css"") %>"" rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" />";

Match myMatch = myRegex.Match(strTargetString);
```

The difference here is using [`Regex.Matches(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which returns a [`MatchCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); every matched occurence) vs [`Regex.Match(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which returns a single [`Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); the first matched occurence only).

Comment: I dont want to use foreach loop here. Is there anything, where I can assign "myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))" value to "myMatch" directly.

When I am using "Match myMatch = myRegex.Matches(strTargetString);", I am getting null value in myMatch.

Comment: @Kanaiya well `Matches(string)` returns a [`MatchCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.aspx), so every match. If you only want one single match, use [`Match(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx), this will return the first occurence (if any). If there is only one occurence of `<link href=...` then you'll be fine with `Match myMatch = myRegex.Match(strTargetString)` and no for-loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works, But i GET {("~/Styles/CAR.css")}.
I just need ~/Styles/CAR.css to get extracted.
I tried editing your Regex, but still, i am unable to get desirable output. Pls let me know the Regex to get output value.

Comment: @Kanaiya most likely this is NOT a problem with the regex. The **whole match** is `("~/Styles/CAR.css")` since we _match_ on `("` and `")`, too! You only want to extract the first [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) only! This could be done with `myMatch.Groups[1].Value` (but be careful: the [Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx)-property won't have two (or more) members when the regex fails to match!)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (available from NuGet) for HTML parsing. Getting `href` attribute value will look like:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(stringWithHtml);
var link = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//link[@href]");
var href = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
```

Then you can extract `~/Styles/CAR.css` from content of attribute. Regex is good here, but you also can avoid it:

```
int startIndex = href.IndexOf('"');
int endIndex = href.LastIndexOf('"');
var result = href.Substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex - startIndex - 1);
// ~/Styles/CAR.css
```

Extracting path with regex will look like

```
var match = Regex.Match(href, @"ResolveClientUrl\(""(.*)""\)");
if (match.Success)
    result = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
/\(([^\)]*)\)/
```

Tested with perl:

```
> cat temp
<link href="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Styles/CAR.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
> perl -lne 'print $1 if(/\(([^\)]*)\)/)' temp
"~/Styles/CAR.css"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

<link href="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Styles/CAR.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

For quick regex we can use the information inside the quotes inside parentheses (("~/Styles/CAR.css") ) and use that info to group it into one one.

Escaping the parentheses one quick regex would be

<link href="<%=.*\("(.*)\).*%>"(.*/>)

In the above regex there are two groups. The first matched group would give us the required information i.e. ~/Styles/CAR.css.

You can check it in http://regexpal.com/ and experiment with other patterns.